# Insert Commas into ACF number field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am displaying numbers (non currency) via an advance custom field of `paid_attendance` - however by default number fields in ACF do not include commas or decimals etc.

I would like for commas to be included when the numbers from `paid_attendance` are output to the user on the front end. I am aware this can be done through the template file but I need to make it global via functions.php. I am probably way off, but below is the code I put together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Return number with commas
function fix_number( $wpdb ) {
$number = get_field('paid_attendance');
number_format($number)."<br>";
}
add_action('fix_number');
```

**EDIT**
Below is the fix and I have now got it working. Clearly and as Rick mentioned I was not using hooks properly. After reading deeper into the ACF docs and consulting other users on their forum, I was able to do what I need.

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=paid_attendance', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value);
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: I would try ACF's support channels as they can tell you how best to format globally. I believe you can add a filter to `get_field` so if the field name is `paid_attendance` you can take the value and format as desired, which will then apply everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'hook' your function to a valid hook. Your `add_action` call is not doing anything, because it is not a proper call to a hook.. See the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/ for `add_action`.

Your function is the second parameter of the `add_action` hook. The first parameter is 'where' to hook into WordPress. If you want to modify the post content, then hook into `the_content` (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/ ).

But, then you need to parse `the_content` to find a number to format. The `the_content` hook works on the **entire** post (or page) content, so your function won't work.

So, not sure that you can do what you want. But if you are going to use hooks, then you need to learn how they work. The above links are a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. Clearly I have a lot of learning to do. I made an edit to my original post with the fix that has worked for me. Appreciate your time and I am going to dig into the links you posted.